# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null even if $wpdb already declared

Tags: php, wordpress

I've recently just started doing projects in Wordpress, specifically with plugins. So, I have a dynamic dependent dropdown that uses AJAX that I want to show in an admin plugin menu where I am using $wpdb object for the queries. The problem is using get_results() for my query results in a "Call to a member get_results() on null" even though I already declared global $wpdb.

I've tried adding

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
```

on my AJAX url location, it didn't work.

## index.php

//For enqueuing script

```
function data_capture_tool_filter() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-filter', plugins_url('/js/ajax-script.js',__FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
```

## ajax-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cluster').on('change', function() {
        var cluster_id = $(this).val();
        if (cluster_id) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost/csccrc/wp-content/plugins/wp-csc-crc/pages/ajax_test.php',
            data: 'id=' + cluster_id,
            success: function(html) {
              $('#issue').html(html);
            }
          });
        }
        alert(cluster_id);
      });
});
```

## ajax_test.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {
    //Get all state data
    $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_issues");
    echo $query;

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select issue</option>';
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Issue not available</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

## Data Capture Tool Page

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Thematic Clusters dropdown  -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select id="cluster" name="cluster">
        <option value="">Thematic Clusters</option>
        <?php foreach ($clusters as $cluster) : ?>
          <?= '<option value="' . $cluster->id . '">' . $cluster->name . '</option>' ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Issues dropdown -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select id="issue" name="issue">
        <option value="">Issues</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Articles dropdown -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select id="article" name="article">
        <option value="">Articles</option>
        <?php foreach ($articles as $article) : ?>
          <?= '<option value="' . $article->id . '">' . $article->title . '</option>' ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

Comment: im no WP expert, but when it says `->get_results()` on `null`, then it means `$wpdb` is not an object it seems. debug `$wpdb` inside that file to find out why

Comment: It just displays a blank page. It's totally weird because I am able to use $wpdb in other pages without any other problem.

Comment: Please use wordpress ajax. for more info, see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))